# Spilt dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that read using pandas, I' want to split the dataframe in chunks in  a specified column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_of_classes=[]
# Reading file
fileName = 'Training.csv'
df       = pd.read_csv(fileName)
classID  = df.iloc[:,-2]
len(classID)
df.iloc[0,-2]
for i in range(len(classID)):
    print(classID[i])
    if classID[i] not in list_of_classes:
        list_of_classes.append(classID[i])


for i in range(len(df)):
  ...............................
```

**UPDATE**

Say the dataframe looks like :

```
........................................
Feature0  Feature1  Feature2  Feature3  ......... classID lastColum 


 190       565     35474  0.336283   2.973684       255         0   
 311       984    113199  0.316057   3.163987       155         0   
 310       984     94197  0.315041   3.174194      1005         0   
 280       984    116359  0.284553   3.514286       255        18   
 249       984    107482  0.253049   3.951807      1005         0   
 283       984    132343  0.287602   3.477032       155         0   
 213       984     88244  0.216463   4.619718       255         0   
 839       984    203139  0.852642   1.172825       255         0   
 376       984    105133  0.382114   2.617021      1005         0   
 324       984    129209  0.329268   3.037037      1005         0
```

in this example the result that I'm aiming to get, is 3 dataframes, each of them has only 1 classID either 155, 1005, or 255.
my question is, is there a finer way to do this ?

Comment: finer than what?

Comment: Based on what? Where's your code? There's hardly any detail here. Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986372/split-pandas-dataframe-into-separate-pieces-based-on-column-values

Comment: sorry code got lost

Comment: @MaximilianPeters and edChum is the question now clearer ?

Comment: @Engine, it's not clear what do you want to "split". Can you post a small reproducible data set and desired data set(s) - this would help us to understand what are you trying to do. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @MaxU I've update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split to 3 separate CSV files:

```
df.groupby('classID') \
  .apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(r'c:/temp/{}.csv'.format(x.name), index=False))
```

Generate a dictionary of "splitted" DataFrames:

```
In [210]: dfs = {g:x for g,x in df.groupby('classID')}

In [211]: dfs.keys()
Out[211]: dict_keys([155, 255, 1005])

In [212]: dfs[155]
Out[212]:
   Feature0  Feature1  Feature2  Feature3  classID  lastColum
1       311       984    113199  0.316057      155          0
5       283       984    132343  0.287602      155          0

In [213]: dfs[255]
Out[213]:
   Feature0  Feature1  Feature2  Feature3  classID  lastColum
0       190       565     35474  0.336283      255          0
3       280       984    116359  0.284553      255         18
6       213       984     88244  0.216463      255          0
7       839       984    203139  0.852642      255          0

In [214]: dfs[1005]
Out[214]:
   Feature0  Feature1  Feature2  Feature3  classID  lastColum
2       310       984     94197  0.315041     1005          0
4       249       984    107482  0.253049     1005          0
8       376       984    105133  0.382114     1005          0
9       324       984    129209  0.329268     1005          0
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help,  how may I avoid this error :
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/temp/1020.csv'
?

Comment: do you have such a directory: `c:/temp/`? If not you would need to change it correspondingly...

Comment: well the creation I guess of the csv file, I need to check, not on right device now. thanks  a lot

Comment: just wanted to tell, that it's working perfectly, thanks !

Comment: @Engine, glad it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abcdef'), 'part': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})

parts = df.part.unique()

for part in parts:
    print df.loc[df.part == part]
```

So the point is that you take all unique parts by calling `unique()` on series that you want to use for split.

After that, you can access those parts via loop and do whatever you need on each one of them.